# Managed Bean not found after upgrading mojarra 2.2.8 to 2.2.14

Tags: jsf-2.2, embedded-jetty, mojarra

I use jetty-webapp 9.4.0.v2016120, and I try to upgrade jsf implementation (mojarra) from 2.2.8 to 2.2.14

After upgrading my Managed Bean are not found. I noticed that AnnotationScaner is null in ConfigManager class

```
  AnnotationScanner annotationScanner = this.metadataGetter.getAnnotationScanner();
```

Someone now how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Here are my pom dependencies:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-webapp -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
  <version>9.4.0.v20161208</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
  <version>9.4.0.v20161208</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-api -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.14</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.14</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.el/javax.el-api -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1-b04</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.web/el-impl -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.1-b05</version>
</dependency>
```